# php html Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php

i feel this is going to be something stupid but i cant seem to get this to work what im trying to do is read through a file and extract all the appropriate web addresses but when i run this i get a fatal error, i get the feeling im initiating an infinate loop but i cant find it

```
    $contents = file_get_contents("../uploads/bookmarks.html");
$find   = 'https://www.example.net/e/';
$i = 0;
do{
    if(strpos($contents, $find)){
        $check = true;
        $contents = strstr($contents,$find);
        $temp = explode('"', $contents, 2);
        echo $temp[0];
    }else{
        $check = false;
    }
}while($check = true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning $check = true instead of comparing the two values. Turn

`while($check = true)`

to

`while ($check === true)`

Comment: @Sebas has a 'better' solution of just using `while($check)`. It is less redundant.

Comment: @Jasper Actually assignment happens before the expression is checked. Or else the old standard `while($row = mysql_fetch($res))` would infinite loop.

Comment: Ignore me, I've been coding JS all day.

Comment: But isn't this going to keep looping if the string is found in the file?  `$check` will always be `true`.

Comment: @Sebas Or for those who aren't into the whole brevity thing: `while($check === true)` :)

Comment: @danmullen no not necessarily since $contents is being modified using strstr on every loop

Comment: On that note, I'd also change `strpos($contents, $find)` to something more explicit like `strpos($contents, $find) !== false`. I don't really like the chameleon aptitude of the php functions returns...